# Create Trigger for Update with condition in Sybase ASA16

Tags: triggers, updates, sybase, sybase-asa

I want to create a trigger with condition, there's 2 table Trx (Columns = TrxResp, Prodcode, TrxFwdIID, TrxTType) and Deposit (Columns = AccountXID, Balance).

The case is if table Trx update with conditon where TrxResp in (51,55) and Prodcode in (101001, 103001) and TrxFwdIID = (28) and TrxTType in (30,1,49,46), then trigger will update column Balance in table Deposit with this condition:

```
@Amount = 2000
@Accountxid = 123

update Deposit set Balance = Balance - @Amount where AccountXID = @AccountXID;
```

I tried to write the script like below but I guess I'm completely wrong

```
CREATE TRIGGER "UpdateDepositBalance" after update OF prodcode in (101001, 103001),trxFwdIId = 28,trxttype in (30,1,49,46),trxresp in (51,55) 
on TRx
for each row
begin
declate @Amount int;
declare @Accountxid int;
    
    set @Amount = 2000
    set @Accountxid = 123
    update Deposit set Balance = Balance - @Amount where AccountXID = @AccountXID;
    end;
```

Can someone help me, please. I'm so weak at triggers and SP

Comment: You state "SyBase" in your title, and yet tag MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL in your tags. What RDBMS are you ***really*** using?

Comment: I'm sorry, already edited

Comment: what do you mean by 'completely wrong'? are you getting an error during creation or execution (and if so, what error)? is the trigger not firing? trigger is firing but the row is not getting updated (or it's updated but with wrong value)?

Comment: Have you reviewed [these SQLAnywhere 16 trigger examples](http://dcx.sybase.com/sa160/en/dbreference/create-trigger-statement.html)? take a look at the 3rd example from the bottom that has a `if` test ... I'm guessing you could chain a few of these `if` statements together to meet your requirements